# the codeigniter 3 pagination button only displays the record on the first page with SQL server 2008

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-server-2008, pagination

now i am making a website application using codeigniter 3 with SQL server 2008 database.

I want to use the pagination feature to display all records with 10 records per page.

I've created the MVC file and the record and pagination buttons have been displayed.

but when I will press the next button in the pagination button to display the next record, nothing happens. in other words still remain on the first page with the first record displayed (10 records shown).

here is my MVC;

Controller(menu.php):

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Menu extends CI_Controller
{
 
 public function server1()
 {
  $this->load->view('server/db1');
 }
 
  public function iat_dev()
  {
   $this->load->view('server/db1/iat_dev');
  }
  
  public function iat_live()
  {
   $this->load->view('server/db1/iat_live');
  }
  
  public function iat_test()
  {
   $this->load->view('server/db1/iat_test');
  }
  
  public function iatm()
  {
   $this->load->view('server/db1/iatm');
  }
  
  public function imp_sys()
  {
   $this->load->view('server/db1/imp_sys');
  }
  
  public function import_statistic()
  {
   $this->load->view('server/db1/import_statistic');
  }
  
   public function galic()
   {
    $this->load->helper(array('url'));
    $this->load->model('server/db1/import_statistic/model_galic');
    $this->load->library('kode_negara'); //library buatan sendiri
    $this->kode_negara->list_negara();
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    
    //$kueri = $this->model_galic->tampil_data(); //$this->[class model]->[function model]();
    //$data = array('hasil' => $kueri); //array('[variabel yg ditampilkan di view]'
    
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'menu/galic';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('galic')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    
    $config['first_link']       = 'Pertama';
    $config['last_link']        = 'Terakhir';
    $config['next_link']        = 'Berikut';
    $config['prev_link']        = 'Sebelum';
    $config['full_tag_open']    = '<div class="text-center"><nav><ul class="pagination justify-content-center">';
    $config['full_tag_close']   = '</ul></nav></div>';
    $config['num_tag_open']     = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['num_tag_close']    = '</span></li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open']     = '<li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['cur_tag_close']    = '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>';
    $config['next_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['next_tagl_close']  = '<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></span></li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['prev_tagl_close']  = '</span></li>';
    $config['first_tag_open']   = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = '</span></li>';
    $config['last_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['last_tagl_close']  = '</span></li>';
    //class disabled untuk menonaktifkan 
    
    $from = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['hasil'] = $this->model_galic->tampil_data($config['per_page'],$from);
    $this->load->view('server/db1/import_statistic/galic', $data);
   }
   
   public function ikpp()
   {
    $this->load->view('server/db1/import_statistic/ikpp');
   }
   
   public function master_imp()
   {
    $this->load->view('server/db1/import_statistic/master_imp');
   }
   
   public function tblrpths()
   {
    $this->load->view('server/db1/import_statistic/tblrpths');
   }
   
   public function tk()
   {
    $this->load->view('server/db1/import_statistic/tk');
   }
   
  public function reportserver()
  {
   $this->load->view('server/db1/reportserver');
  }
  
  public function reportservertempdb()
  {
   $this->load->view('server/db1/reportservertempdb');
  }
  
 public function server2()
 {
  $this->load->view('server/db2');
 }
 
 public function database()
 {
  $this->load->view('info/db');
 }
 
 public function versiphp()
 {
  $this->load->view('info/php');
 }
 
}
```

---

Model(model_galic.php):

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_galic extends CI_Model
{
 function tampil_data(){
  $this->load->database('sqlsrv_import_statistic', TRUE);
  $limit = '1';
  $offset = '10';
  $sql = "DECLARE
    @LIMIT AS INT = $limit,
    @OFFSET AS INT = $offset
    SELECT  *
    FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY convert(datetime,tanggalPIB,103) ) AS NoBaris, *
        FROM      GALIC
      ) AS RowConstrainedResult
    WHERE   NoBaris >= $limit
    AND  NoBaris <= $offset
    ORDER BY NoBaris";
  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
  return $query;
 }
}
```

---

View(galic.php):

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Indo Asia | Tabel GALIC</title>
   <?php include 'application/views/komponen/header.php'; //meta, css, js ?>
 </head>
<body>
 <?php include 'application/views/komponen/navbar.php'; //navbar ?>

<div class="container text-center">    
 <div class="row content">
  <div class="col-sm-12 text-left"> 
   <h2>Tabel GALIC</h2>
   <hr>
   <form class="form" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>menu/cari_galic" method="POST">
    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="label_hs">HS:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control" name="hs" placeholder="Kode HS" />
     </div>    
     <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="label_importir">Importir:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control" name="importir" placeholder="Nama Importir" />
     </div>
     <!--datepicker awal-->
     <div class="form-group col-md-2">
     <label for="label_tglawal">Tanggal Awal:</label>
      <div class="input-daterange" id="datepicker">
       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control" name="tglawal" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" />
      </div>
     </div> 
     <div class="form-group col-md-2">
     <label for="label_tglakhir">Tanggal Akhir:</label>     
      <div class="input-daterange" id="datepicker">
       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control" name="tglakhir" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" />
      </div>
     </div>
     <!--datepicker akhir-->
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="tabel" value="cari">Cari</button>
   </form>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
     <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
       <th>No</th>
       <th>NoPengajuan</th>
       <th>TanggalPIB</th>
       <th>TanggalBLAWB</th>
       <th>PelabuhanAsal</th>
       <th>PelabuhanTujuan</th>
       <th>NPWP</th>
       <th>Importir</th>
       <th>AlamatImportir</th>
       <th>PPJK</th>
       <th>AlamatPPJK</th>
       <th>Pemasok</th>
       <th>AlamatPemasok</th>
       <th>NegaraPemasok</th>
       <th>HS</th>
       <th>UraianBarang</th>
       <th>Quantity</th>
       <th>KodeSatuan</th>
       <th>Berat</th>
       <th>HargaCIF</th>
       <th>MataUang</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <?php
      $no=1;
      foreach($hasil->result() as $baris)
      {
     ?>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($no++,0,",",".")?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->NoPengajuan; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->TanggalPIB; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->TanggalBLAWB; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->PelabuhanAsal; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->PelabuhanTujuan; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->NPWP; ?></td>      
       <td><?php echo $baris->Importir; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->AlamatImportir; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->PPJK; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->AlamatPPJK; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->Pemasok; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->AlamatPemasok; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo strtoupper($this->kode_negara->list_negara($baris->NegaraPemasok)); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->HS; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->UraianBarang; ?></td>
       <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($baris->Quantity,0,",","."); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->KodeSatuan; ?></td>
       <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($baris->Berat,0,",","."); ?></td>
       <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($baris->HargaCIF,2,",","."); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $baris->MataUang; ?></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
     <?php
      }
     ?>
    </table>
   </div>
   <?php
    echo '<p>'.$this->db->count_all_results('galic'/*nama tabel*/).' record(s) ditampilkan</p>';
    echo $this->pagination->create_links();
   ?>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

 <?php include 'application/views/komponen/footer.php'; //footer ?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

where is my syntax writing error?

Answer (score 0):

you didn't use the offset you throw from controller to your model.
From your controller:

```
$data['hasil'] = $this->model_galic->tampil_data($config['per_page'],$from);
```

To Your Model:

```
function tampil_data(){
        $this->load->database('sqlsrv_import_statistic', TRUE);
        $limit = '1';
        $offset = '10';
        $sql = "DECLARE
                @LIMIT AS INT = $limit,
                @OFFSET AS INT = $offset
                SELECT  *
                FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY convert(datetime,tanggalPIB,103) ) AS NoBaris, *
                          FROM      GALIC
                        ) AS RowConstrainedResult
                WHERE   NoBaris >= $limit
                AND     NoBaris <= $offset
                ORDER BY NoBaris";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query;
    }
```

Do not declare your offset on the model.instead the $from on your controller must be used as offset on the model.

Comment: If im not mistaken. the $limit is for the number of record to be shown per page and the $offset should be where to start from the query. If that so, the $limit must be equal to 10 and the $offset should be the $from on the controller. :)